# Disable GameObject but continue to run Coroutine

Tags: c#, coroutine, unity-game-engine

I have a `BonusController` script as a component of a `Bonus` gameObject. This Bonus must be destroyed on collision but has to "act" for a few seconds. I have started a coroutine for this, but the script stops its execution (I think it's because I set the gameObject inactive). Here is the code of `BonusController`:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    StartCoroutine(speedUp(1));
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

IEnumerator speedUp(float seconds)
{
    Debug.Log("before");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    Debug.Log("after"); // <--- This is never called
}
```

How can I remove the object and don't stop the coroutine script execution?

Comment: FOR INVOKE REPEATING... (1) disable whole game object - InvokeRepeating does not stop (2) disable just the script component - InvokeRepeating does not stop BUT FOR COROUTINES... (3) disable whole game object - coroutine DOES STOP (also it DOES NOT "come back" if you reenable the whole game object) (4) disable just the script component - coroutine does not stop. Finally (5) if you Destroy the component or the whole game object that DOES stop BOTH invokerepeatings and coroutines.  DON'T FORGET THAT to disable a "whole game object" -> SetActive, to disable "just a component" -> .enable

Comment: in short, of the four combinations, if you disable a whole game object (ie, SetActive(false)), that DOES stop coroutines. in all other cases of disabling, both invokes and coroutines "keep going forever".  (I have never know why that case works differently.) In all cases if you completely destroy the component or object, that DOES stop all invokes/coroutines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you just disable the `mesh renderer` and `collider`? This way the gameobject will still exists, but the user won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pull the ground on which you are standing. :)

Just disable the `SpriteRenderer` as you are using 2D methods. And keep the object alive and enable.

```
{
    StartCoroutine(speedUp(1));
    //gameObject.SetActive (false);
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = false;
    GetComponent<Collider2D> ().enabled = false;
    // Above line will deactivate the first collider it will find.
}

IEnumerator speedUp(float seconds)
{
    Debug.Log("before");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    Debug.Log("after"); // <--- This is never called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to destroy the object after some time, call destroy inside the coroutine after the yield.

```
yield return WaitForSeconds(second);
Destroy(this);
```

Now it is properly destroyed and will free up memory opposed to still being there, invisible, but taking up resources.

Comment: Don't do this - good news, you can just give `Destroy` a time argument, meaning to wait that long.  **But don't do this anyway** -  you can in fact control 'whether or not" a coroutine stops running, exactly as the OP wants to know. it is a basic and common aspect of programming Unity.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you not ever destroy?  Are there not cases where leaving a bunch of instances lying around become detrimental or performance? Thanks for the clarity, btw.

Comment: Sure, there are many cases in Unity development where you use "Destroy" (or even "DestroyImmediate").  *In the case at hand* the pedagogical issue is that the OP and anyone reading needs to understand the notion that you can simply  (and specifically) disable either the object/component (and the various reasons to do that)